# Computing product of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Consider the random variable $X=I\cdot B$, where $I$ is an bernoulli random with parameter $p$ variable and B an arbitrary r.v.

Why does the following hold $P(X=5)= p \cdot P(B=5)$. What do I use here?

Comment: Are you given that $I$ and $B$ are independent ?

Comment: If I assume they are independent, why does it hold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $I$ is either $0$ or $1$, therefore the event that $X$ is equal to $5$ is the event that $I = 1$ and $B = 5$. *If* $I$ and $B$ are independent, then...
Can you take it from there ?

Comment: So I have $P(I=1, B=5)=P(I=1)P(B=5)$

Comment: Without independency this wont work in another way?

Comment: In the general situation, we have $P(X=5) = P(I=1, B=5)$. For this last quantity to be equal to $P(I=1)P(B=5)$, it is sufficient that $I$ and $B$ are independent, but not necessary. You should try to make two concrete examples, in both of which $I$ and $B$ are *not* independent, and in one of which $P(I=1, B=5)$ is equal to $P(I=1)P(B=5)$, and in the other of which, it isn't.